# geting values from nuxt vuex module, using id from another module

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i have my data stored like this:

**store/resellers.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    all: {
        "1": {
            name: "John´s coffee",
            city: 1,
        },
        "2": {
            name: "Mary´s restaurant",
            city: 2,
        },
        "3": {
            name: "Robertas Pizza",
            city: 2,
        },
        "4": {
            name: "Au cheval",
            city: 1,
        }
    }
})
```

**store/cities.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    all: {
        "1": {
            name: "New York",
            slug: "new-york",
            image: "imagem-from-new-york.jpg"
        },
        "2": {
            name: "Denver",
            slug: "denver",
            image: "imagem-from-denver.jpg"
        }
    }
})
```

**Questions:**

1. In my vue component how can i get the name, slug and image from cities using the city id in resellers?
2. After that How can i group the result using city as key?
3. This way of store data is a best practice? I mean, ID is good as key?
4. This way of relate data is a best practice?

I´m really stuck on this relational object data topic.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: For your no 3 question, it's better to use array

Comment: why? just for clarification i´ve change from array after read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data and this https://medium.com/js-dojo/structuring-vuex-modules-for-relationships-speed-and-durability-de25f7403643